# How to open an application through C++?

Tags: c++

I'd like to open a PDF file through my C++ application. So I want to open a PDF program and pass the filename to it as the parameter. How can I do this?

On Windows, it's a console application.

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Consider `system()`...

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On  Windows use `ShellExecute` with `open` command and just pass the path to the PDF file. system will do the rest.

Comment: So I just need to pass the PDF file path and not the PDF program path?

Comment: @Slasher, yes windows will find out which program is associated with pdf files and run it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on which operating system you are using. In linux your answer is here http://www.gidforums.com/t-3369.html